# Как объединить 2 массива?

Tags: массивы, c++

Есть 2 массива с числами, есть 3-й массив - пустой. Как переписать элементы из 1 и 2 массивов в 3-й буз повторений элементов? n - размерность 1 массива, k - второго

```
int a[100], b[100], c[100];
for (int i=0; i <n; i++) c[i] = a[i];

int kol = n;

for  ( int j =0; j < k; j++)
  for ( int z=0; z <n; z++)
   if (b[k] != c[z] ) {
        c[kol--] = b[k];
        kol++;
   }
```

Я написал только такой код, но в с переписываются только элементы из а

Comment: Может в коде поменять "k" на "kol", раз уж так инициализировано?

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov, ничего не изменилось(

Answer (score 3):

Сначала загоняем в массив "с" все значения из "b" (при условии, что значения в b не совпадают).

```
for(int i=0; i<ib; i++) // ib - количество элементов в "b[]"
 {
 for(int j=0; j<ic; j++)// iс - количество элементов в "с[]"
  if(b[i]==c[j])
   break;               // если нашли совпадение, переходим на другой шаг цикла.
                        // если Break'a не было, выполняется нижеследующее
  c[ic]=b[i];           // заносим новое значение
  ic++;                 // увеличиваем размер "c[]"      
 }
```

P.S. Если элементы в массиве "а" могут повторяться, то приведенный выше цикл повторяется два раза. С заменой b[] на a[] и установкой значения ic=1.